Проверка значения title и скрытие блока div
Есть два div:
<div class="warning1" title = "Леопард">
<p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning2">
<p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>

Можно ли с помощью css проверить содержимое title warning1 и если title не равен "Леопард" то скрыть warning2?
.warning2
{
display: none;
}

<div class="header" ><div class="navigation-bar-width-sticky header-view__left-area" ><div 
class="button hamburger header-view__button header-view__button_hamburger">
    <div class="button__content">
        
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-logo header-view__logo">
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="header-view__main">
             <div class="entity-creation-menu header-view__entity-creation-menu" title="Создать"><div  class="button popup-button__button entity-creation-menu__popup-button">
                 <div class="button__content button__content_has-text button__content_has-icon popup-button__button-content" title="Создать н">
                     <span class="button__text popup-button__button-text">11</span>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="global-search-panel header-view__search"><div class="search-panel global-search-panel__search-panel" id="global-search-panel"><input class="search-panel__text global-search-panel__search-panel-text" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Искать " value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="button global-search-panel__advanced-search-button"><div class="button__content button__content_has-text">
                        <span class="button__text">поиск</span>
                        </div></div></div></div>
                        <div class="header-view__right-area">
                            <div tabindex="-1" id="widgets-context-button" class="button header-view__button"><div class="button__content" >
                                <</div>
                                <</div>
                                <div class="current-user-info header-view__button" title="11">
                                    <div tabindex="-1"  class="button popup-button__button current-user-info__popup-button"><div class="button__content popup-button__button-content current-user-info__popup-button-content" data-has-expander="false" title="Леопард"></div></div></div></div></div>

И вот нужно скрыть
class="global-search-panel header-view__search" если title в current-user-info не равен "Леопард".

Да, проверить содержимое title возможно с помощью селектора по атрибуту:


.warning1[title="Леопард"] + .warning2 { display: none; }
<div class="warning1" title="Леопард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 1</p>
</div>

<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 2</p>
</div>





мне нужно проверить что title не равен "Леопард" И если он не равен,то скрывать...

Тогда необходимо в селектор добавить псевдокласс :not() :


.warning1:not([title="Леопард"]) + .warning2 { display: none; }
<div class="warning1" title="Гепард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 1</p>
</div>

<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 2</p>
</div>





Есть ли возможность проверить значение если к примеру проверить title,если блок который нужно скрыть идет раньше чем блок который нужно проверить?

Такая возможность появилась относительно недавно, и позволяет это псевдокласс :has():


:root:has(.warning1:not([title="Леопард"])) .warning2 { display: none; }
<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 2</p>
</div>

<div class="warning3">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 3</p>
</div>

<div class="warning4">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 4</p>
</div>

<div class="warning1" title="Гепард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard 1</p>
</div>



Псевдокласс :root в этом примере указан только как замена общего родительского контейнера.

Спасибо, единственное тут проверка идет на полное совпадение. А у меня с кажем несколько вариантов title и мне нужно проверять что если они не равны  "Леопард",то тогда скрывать

@Сергей, приведите пример.

Ну скажем у меня

Beware of the leopard 1

И мне нужно проверить что  title не равен "Леопард"
И если он не равен,то скрывать 

Beware of the leopard 2

А если равен,то условие соответственно не срабатывает и блок видно

Грубо говоря равно поменять на не равно
.warning1[title="Леопард"] + .warning2 { display: none; }

@Сергей, добавил вариант.

Большое Спасибо

Небольшое уточнение
Поменяется структура записи
Если div являются дочерними и  содержаться еще в нескольких
div?

@Сергей, меньше слов и больше кода ;-)

Добавил в вопрос)

При простом примере когда всегда два div все работает,а во втором примере почему то нет

Я так понял дело в "+" т.к.   это означает стиль применяется только к абзацам, следующим непосредственно за другим абзацем.
А если перед нужным мне абзацем несколько абзацев к примеру

Есть ли возможность проверить значение если к примеру  проверить  title,если блок который нужно скрыть идет раньше чем блок который нужно проверить?

Beware of the leopard 2


Beware of the leopard 3


Beware of the leopard 4


Beware of the leopard 1
